# call a oracle function that returns a record from mybatis 3

Tags: spring, oracle, plsql, mybatis, ibatis

i have this function in oracle:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION rmc_getPublicaciones (yearr IN number)

RETURN publicacionisi%ROWTYPE    
IS
publtotal publicacionisi%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT * into publtotal
   FROM publicacionisi p where p.py = yearr;
   RETURN publtotal;
END;
```

and i want to call it from mybatis and put the result in a resultmap

```
<select id="getAllPublicaciones"  parameterType="int" statementType="CALLABLE" resultMap="resMapPublicacionIsi" useCache="false">
         select desa.rmc_getPublicaciones(#{py}) from dual
</select>
```

what should i do to make this work?
i could do the same just using 
`select * from publicacionisi p where p.py={#py}` but i wanna see if there is some difference in performance doing this in a function in the database.

Comment: what doesn't work? What errors do you get, if any?

Answer (score 1):

For me the old iBatis way of calling functions still works, although XML tags changed a bit:

Map (probably should be exchanged for `parameterType` in this case, but I didn't test that):

```
<parameterMap id="getAllPublicacionesParams" type="map">
    <parameter property="property_name" jdbcType="NUMERIC" javaType="int" mode="IN"/>
</parameterMap>
```

Call:

```
<select id="getAllPublicaciones" parameterMap="getAllPublicacionesParams" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { ? = call desa.rmc_getPublicaciones(?) }
</select>
```